# What is the use of "Add view from template"?

Tags: views

As when we select the view options three links appears but I don't understand what is the use of "**Add view from template**"

[image]

because when we click on this link we get this one...

[image]

and after further proceeding normal view is created. so what is the use of that link?

Comment: Have you clicked it and compared what you got with regular "add new view"? If so, haven't you noticed any differences?

Comment: When I go through the link (the link create by that view) it show nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Modules give you some templates to work with instead of having to figure out the dirty details yourself.

For example:

You have the image module installed, so they give you a gallery template to work with. of course you're not obligated to use it but it's there.

If you download the [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module it will give you a bunch of templates as well.

[image]

There are several modules that give you templates to work with. And if you write your own custom modules, you to have access to create templates for users to use if you wish to.